# Send files from raspberry pi to smartphone Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, python, raspberry-pi

I wouldlike a script (python) for send files (audio) to my smartphone with bluetooth. Example : i have a file on my Documents, when my raspberry pi start, the script start and send my file to my smartphone with bluetooth.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wouldlike to send a files (.wav) from my raspberry pi to my phone.

Comment: sorry i failed, i wanted to said "from" Raspberry Pi. "Documtents" it's an example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could start looking around PyBluez is an effort to create python wrappers around system Bluetooth resource:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pybluez/

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something similar with help of an Arduino and two android phones.

The way i tackled it was by using NFC (a (very) short range bluetooth, stands for Near Field Communication). This way i could 'Beam' text from one device to another, a quick google and i came up with this: http://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/beam.html i'm not quite sure if it's enough and/or capable in transferring Audio files, but it might be worth the read, and i hope it gets you in the right direction.

Feel free to ask anything related to what i did.

PS: would like to include some source code, but unfortunatly i removed it as it was a short-lived project.